# C++ Connecting two .cpp files

Tags: c++

I have a problem connecting two .cpp files in C++. Here are my files

Header.h

```
//Header.h
template <class T> class asd{
asd();
check();
print();
}
```

file1.cpp

```
//file1.cpp
//defines all methods in class asd
#include "Header.h"
template<class T> asd<T>:: asd(T a, T b){//codes}
template<class T> T asd<T>:: check(T a){//codes}
template<class T> void asd<T>::print(){//codes}
```

file2.cpp

```
//file2.cpp
//main method
#include "Header.h"
int main(){//codes}
```

The thing I do not understand is that the code runs fine when I put main() inside file1.cpp, but it wont compile when I separate them into two files. Can someone please give pointers?

Edit:
For those with the same problem, solution can be found here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/14272/

Comment: You can't put generic template definitions in a separate file from the declarations.

Comment: I apologize for this is a repeated question. I have found my solution online. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Member functions of a class template should appear in the header file. Just move the function definitions from `file1.cpp` to `Header.h`.

Imagine you are the compiler. When compiling `main`, if you attempt to instantiate `asd` in any way, the compiler needs to be able to see the function definitions to generate the appropriate code. For example, if in `main` you do `asd<int> my_asd;`, the compiler needs to instantiate `asd` with `T` replaced with `int`. It can't do that for the functions if it can't see the function definitions.

Comment: This would work if the problem wasnt specifically asking for us to make two separate .cpp files. Sorry I was not very clear with my question. Regardless, thanks for your response!

Comment: @user2205010 Some people like to have a `.h` file and a `.tpp` file, and you `#include` the `.tpp` file *at the bottom* of the `.h` file. This achieves the same thing.

Comment: Yes that could also be an answer. I have found my best solution and posted it on my original post. Turned out template explicit instantiation fixed my issues. Thank you very much!